How to create a message template with a specified workflow name
CiviRules has long been able to send Activity emails using this code (sites/default/files/civicrm/ext/org.civicoop.civirules/CRM/CivirulesActions/Activity/Add.php line 179 of CiviRules v3.12):

CRM_Case_BAO_Case::sendActivityCopy(NULL, $this->activityId, [$contact['email'] => $contact], NULL, NULL);

Since upgrading CiviCRM from 5.73 to 5.75, this fails with the following log record:
2024-09-14 21:45:48-0400  [error] Rule: '{rule_title}' with id {rule_id} failed for contact {contact_id} because of {reason}
Array
(
    [rule_id] => 1
    [rule_title] => Marshall followup to an Inbound SMS
    [original_error] => No message template with workflow name case_activity.
    [contact_id] => 11156
    [reason] => Failed to execute action
)

As far as I can tell the dependency on case_activity is in Core, sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Case/BAO/Case.php line 1406 of CiviCRM v5.77:
      [$result[$info['contact_id'] ?? NULL], $subject, $message, $html] = CRM_Core_BAO_MessageTemplate::sendTemplate(
        [
          'workflow' => 'case_activity',
          ...

Does this mean that a message template with "workflow name case_activity" is no longer in the CiviCRM release and I need to create it? If so, how do I go about doing that? I know how to create email and SMS templates, but not how to tie them to a "workflow name" nor how to add Activity fields.

It's still there. You can look in the civicrm_msg_template table to check. I can't think why it would go missing on upgrade.
Is this a multilingual install with the message-admin extension installed? It's possible it's looking for the template in another language and there isn't one? I think it would fall back to the default language, but I'm not actually sure how that works.

Thank you Demerit, you got me looking in the right direction. This was self-inflicted. I accidentally deleted that template during some clean up.
